# Can Mathematica put these puzzle pieces together?

Tags: list-manipulation, regions, game

I have five DXF files with various geometric figures.

[image]

Are squares with a different geometric shape in each DXF file...

Four DXF files have a square with a different geometric shape on one side while one DXF file on each side have a different geometric shape, as shown above.

([DXF1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tg1o1c0r80jn1cl/File1.dxf?dl=1),[DXF2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dbd8a3vc5vhoipj/File2.dxf?dl=1),[DXF3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/orbeqg1rks1szqg/File3.dxf?dl=1),[DXF4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1uvlw9r0anb30q6/File4.dxf?dl=1),[DXF5](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4lidjwwec2odsr/File5.dxf?dl=1))

1. It is possible join these 5 files?

[image]

2. Some files are in the wrong position to be mounted. It is possible to rotate them?
3. It is possible to create a code that can recognize these geometries and make some assembly like this? The animation is only illustrative. It was created only to facilitate understanding

[image: Animated gif]

An attempt was made to convert the files above into 2D `BoundaryMeshRegions`, and these can be imported via:

```
meshes = << "http://pastebin.com/raw/zNxS87RP"
```

Comment: Forget about the animation, it isn't necessary to state the question.  Also, a better title might be "Can MMA put these puzzle pieces together".  Finally, you should try to convert these files into 2D `BoundaryMeshRegions` first to make this easier.

Comment: Why are the `MeshRegions` in 3D?

Comment: It was a bit of a pain, had to manually rearrange some indices, but I created 2D meshes from these files:  `meshes = << "http://pastebin.com/raw/zNxS87RP"`

Comment: @Feyre Because normally work with this file type

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho - Hope you don't mind the edits, I think this is an interesting problem

Comment: closely related: [How to find alignments of interlocking shapes?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101137/5478)

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho what do you mean? p.s. also closely related: [Community: 
Programming approach to solving "One Tough Puzzle"](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/858489)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming polygons follow the same (clockwise or counterclockwise) vertex order, find all good quality two line segment rigid mappings between polygons without overlap with each other (at least much overlap, that is). Construct a graph of these mappings and apply appropriate transforms to polygons by finding transform paths from one polygon to all others. (In this case, these paths are pretty simple).

```
ReplaceList[MeshPrimitives[#, 2] & /@ meshes, {___,
    {a : Polygon[{___, ap : Repeated[_, {3}], ___}]}, ___,
    {b : Polygon[{___, bp : Repeated[_, {3}], ___}]}, ___} :>
   Module[{err, trans},
    {err, trans} = 
     Chop[FindGeometricTransform[{ap}, Reverse@{bp}, 
       TransformationClass -> "Rigid", Method -> "Linear"], 0.001];
    {Property[a \[DirectedEdge] b, "trans" -> trans],
      Property[b \[DirectedEdge] a, "trans" -> InverseFunction@trans]} /;
     err < 1 && 
      Quiet@Area[
         RegionIntersection[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@a, 
          BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@TransformedRegion[b, trans]]] < 1]] //
 With[{g = Graph@Flatten@#},
   Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm@Thick, First@VertexList@g,
     GeometricTransformation[#,
        Composition @@ (PropertyValue[{g, DirectedEdge @@ #}, "trans"] & /@ 
           Partition[FindShortestPath[g, First@VertexList@g, #], 2, 1])] & /@
      Rest@VertexList@g}]] &
```

[image]

Comment: such a neat approach...learned a lot from just cursory look +1 :)

Answer (score 22):

For a different approach with image processing, I start with the image of your puzzle.

```
fig = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpue6m.jpg"];
comp = MorphologicalComponents[fig // Binarize];
comp = Colorize[comp, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
cols = DominantColors[comp, 20];
blocks = ColorNegate[Binarize@ColorReplace[comp,
         Cases[cols, Except[cols[[#]]]], .01]] & /@Range[10];
pieces = blocks[[{1, 6, 7, 8, 9}]]
```

[image]

Now I have my puzzle pieces, I can try to match them. First I fix the centrepiece and try to match other

```
cen = pieces[[1]];
```

Now I want to see where does the second piece go. So I use `ImageCorrespondingPoints`.

```
n=2

i1 = cen; i2 = pieces[[2]];
matches = ImageCorrespondingPoints[i1, i2 // ColorNegate];
Show[i1, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[matches[[1]]]}]]
Show[i2, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[matches[[2]]]}]]
```

[image]

The red dots show the corresponding points in each piece. Similarly, you can check the other pieces.

You can crop the images if you want, but make sure the image size remain compatible.

Comment: Amazing. Very cool.